# Couting IP unique visitors and sending it to mysql database

Tags: php, ip, unique, counter

I'd  like to know how can i get information about uniques IP's to my site specify link and store that information in mysql database to particular user.
I need that script count not only http://example.com.com but also ex.: http://example.com/somesub/this/link.
Because i want to develop project in which users get traffic to my system and they get paid.
(Pay to Promote system).
How can i develop this? Any ideas about php code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to find the request IP Address or see [How to get client IP address PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-php).
then at the start of each page of your site you should get this value (which acts like a primary key) and do query to the database to increase the specific counter.

P.S: you will find problems in case the client is using proxy to get to your site, see the link above for more information.